# Locating variable location in assembly

Tags: winapi, assembly, reverse-engineering

From the disassembly code below can I assume that the location `43E010` is a location of the variable that holds the string (as in the comment in the assembly code):

**Disassembly:**

```
...
push    offset loc_43E010
...
push    offset aAllYourBaseAre ; "all your base are belong to us"
...
.rdata:00446074 aAllYourBaseAre db 'all your base are belong to us',0
```

This is a disassembly code from a Win32 application that looks like this:

```
class Foo {
public: 
    string mystring;    
    __declspec(dllexport) void foo();
};

void Foo::foo(){

    printf("foo called");

}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    Foo foo;
    foo.mystring =  "all your base are belong to us";

    return 0;
}
```

Does this instruction: `push    offset loc_43E010` shows that address 43E010 is a offset from the base image of the win32 executable and that its a variable location?

Comment: Does this instruction: "push offset loc_43E010" mean that 43E010 is a variable offset?

Comment: It is the offset of *something*. There is not enough information to know exactly what it is the offset of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll invoke my psychic powers (hi Raymond!) and will make a wild guess that you're seeing something like this:

```
push    ebp
mov     ebp, esp
push    0FFFFFFFFh
push    offset loc_43E010
mov     eax, large fs:0
push    eax
...
mov     large fs:0, eax
```

This is a typical prolog of a function that uses exception handling. In your case, even though there are no try/catch statements, there is a local variable with a non-trivial destructor, which needs to be called in case there is an exception being propagated. The `loc_43E010` is a label for the exception handler for the function.

So, the answer is: no, it's **not** a "variable location".

To learn more about exceptions in Win32 (SEH and C++), check [my OpenRCE article](https://www.openrce.org/articles/full_view/21).

Comment: I see, if this is the case, what is the pattern for a variable assignment, to say a DWORD or std::string variable? BTW, since I think you're an expert on this kind of subject you may want to help me with this also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11194837/function-address Cheers.

Comment: Briefly, an integer assignment will be a `mov` while a `std::string` assignment will be a call of `std::strings::operator=()`. I suggest you to read [this book](http://www.amazon.com/dp/0764574817/), it has a long appendix on recovering compiled code.