# Function address

Tags: c++, winapi

Suppose I have a function defined like this:

```
class Foo() {
  public:
      void bar(MyClass* p, int i, int j, CArray<CArray<int,int>,int> &a);
}

void Foo::bar(MyClass* p, int i, int j, CArray<CArray<int,int>,int> &a){
 // Function body
}
```

For a Win32 application/DLL, that this function is not "exported" how can I be able to find the function address of `bar`, getting the function address of exported function was easy. However getting the function address of non-exported function is a bit hard.

Comment: Pointers to non-static member functions ("methods") may not actually be addresses, by the way.  How member functions are represented as pointer types is implementation-dependent.

Comment: If you have control of this code, then just export it. If not, it is probably not intended for external use.

Comment: Do you simply want the address or the ability to call these functions? There are too many things to be taken care of when working with functions which are private to the DLL such as calling convention, name mangling etc. Are you trying to create an injection vector?

Comment: `Foo::bar` is **not** a function. It is a *member* function.

Comment: See related SO [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10487165/is-it-possible-to-call-a-non-exported-function-that-resides-in-an-exe).

Comment: @dirkgently calling function when I know the function address is pretty easy for me, I have the code for that already.  Also getting function address of exported functions is easy too I have a working code for that too. The only problem I face is getting function address of those "not exported"

Comment: @xybrek: I think you've misread my question. It is one thing to look for an address and quite another to invoke a function using that address (you have to be absolutely certain what the calling convention is, at least on 32 bit) and then passing around the `this` object -- a non-trivial, non-portable, error-prone task. Also, see the link I posted in my other comment.

Comment: @dirkgently Yes I understand, what i'm trying to say is that, I already have an application that can read all the exported functions of a exe or DLL then invoke them as needed, considering everything about the Function spec.

Comment: @xybrek: Yes, but these are *exported* which means they'd have a specific calling convention. You cannot assume the same for private functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to do this in the general case.

Among other problems, if the function is not exported, then *it may not exist*.  The optimizer may inline the function at every location where the function is called.  If this occurs, the function won't have an address because it won't exist in the module.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the the function exist, I have the source code for the win32 pe i'm trying to call non-exported functions. And I can see that the function is used so many times. I only have a scenario that I can't recompile the source as the application is already in production.

Comment: If you only care about one specific function in a known module, compute its RVA ahead-of-time?  This all sounds very suspicious, though (not to mention dangerous).  It would be better to modify the module to export the function, or fix it to do what you need, especially if it is a production application.

Comment: Even if I fix the module, the company is too big to adapt the modified executable for all the devices that have the module running, not considering all the management involvement in this process. So the best case for me is to just do call functions even if its not exported.

Comment: If you have the source, have you considered including it into your application directly?  As you have explained it, your problem is not very well-defined, so it's hard to see what your constraints are or what you are really trying to accomplish.

Comment: I see, to clarify, we have come up with doing "calling the function inside the EXE" so far I have made an application that can bind with a certain EXE (target) and able to call exported functions of the EXE also. Including the source file into my new application is the same thing with just recompiling the target EXE; which is not allowed in my case.

Answer (score 0):

if the functions are in the .dll, you can probably export them using a .def file. It creates an export table after the fact from compiled code as if dllexport had been defined.

Read about it here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d91k01sh(v=vs.80).aspx